# Can HIV patients get further infected by their own blood?

Tags: blood, infection, hiv

A person without HIV can get infected with HIV by, blood already infected with the virus entering into their body (for example).

Can HIV patients get further infected by the for example ingestion of their own blood or even by inserting their own blood again into their own bodies?

Answer (score 5):

### No.

One is either infected or one isn't. There is no middle ground. Infection is defined as

> [invasion and multiplication of microorganisms in body tissues, as in an infectious disease.](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/infection)

Also, biologically speaking, there aren't even viruses added because they remove them from their organism first (draw blood) and then re-insert them

Comment: In this case Jeremy considers infection as the attribute caused by the virus and therefore it could be said that there is not a yes or no answer @Jeremy is therefore asking if ones own blood can afect in one way or another the infection rate (the virus can be more controlled or less controlled, more virulent or less virulent) not if it exists a virus or not as usually people without any medical thought consider to be the term "infection"

Comment: +1 for the answer. And to the OP @Jeremy, even though viral load is an important concept in HIV, if you walk through your proposed mechanism of reinfection, it does not make sense that the overall # of HIV viruses within the body would increase.

Comment: What about latent infection?

Comment: @GrahamChiu I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. A latent infection is still an infection, and latent HIV is known for getting active seemingly randomly.Also, removing latent viruses and adding them back in won't change anything either

Comment: Latent TB - I don't believe the bacillus is actively replicating.